# Every open subset of $\mathbb{R}^{p}$ is the union of a countable collection of closed sets.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I want to prove the following statement which is in *The Elements of Real Analysis* by Robert G. Bartle, on page 67 exercise H:

*Every open subset of $\mathbb{R}^{p}$ is the union of a countable collection of closed sets*.
(Hint: Argue as in the preceding exercise, but this time use closed balls)

I have referred to the to the solution given in this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/426575/big-rudin-1-40-open-set-is-a-countable-union-of-closed-disks), but the approach is different from what the book is asking for. I first show the preceding exercise and its proof, and then I show my attempt at the statement that I want to prove.

**Preceding Exercise:** A subset of $\mathbb{R}^{p}$
  is open *iff* it is the union of a countable collection of open balls.

*proof*.
$(\leftarrow )$ An open ball is an open set, and by property 9.3(c) the union of any collection of open sets in $\mathbb{R}^{p}$
  is indeed open in $\mathbb{R}^{p}$. *That is that the union of a countable collection of open balls is open in* $\mathbb{R}^{p}$, hence it is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^{p}$.

$(\rightarrow)$ Let $G\neq\emptyset$
 , $G\subset\mathbb{R}^{p}$
  be open, let $\{r_{n}\::\: n\in\mathbb{N}\}$
  be an enumeration of all the rational points in $G$
  (that is that each of the $p$
  components of a point of $G$
 , consisting of only rational numbers). Now we let $\mathcal{B}(r_{n},\frac{1}{m_{n}}$)
  where $m_{n}$
  is the smallest natural number such that $\mathcal{B}(r_{n},\frac{1}{m_{n}})\subset G$
 . Clearly,$$\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\mathcal{B}(r_{n},\frac{1}{m_{n}})\subset G$$.

Now if we let $x\in G$
 , since $G$
  is open we know that there exists a ball centered at $x$
 , choose $m$
  such that $\mathcal{B}(x,\frac{2}{m})\subset G$
 . Now it follows from Theorem 6.10 that there exists a rational number $y\in\mathcal{B} (x,\frac{1}{m})$
 ; thus $y\in G$
  and therefore $y=r_{n}\in\{r_{n}\::\: n\in\mathbb{N}\}$
  for some $n$
 . If $x\notin\mathcal{B}(r_{n},\frac{1}{m_{n}})$
  then we must have that $\frac{1}{m_{n}}<\frac{1}{m}$
 . [(why?) $y\in\mathcal{B}(x,\frac{1}{m})$
  implies that the distance $d(x,y)<\frac{1}{m}$
 , while $x\notin\mathcal{B}(r_{n},\frac{1}{m_{n}})=\mathcal{B}(y,\frac{1}{m_{n}})$
  implies that the distance $d(x,y)\geqslant\frac{1}{m_{n}}$
 ; hence $\frac{1}{m_{n}}<\frac{1}{m}$
 ]. Now, clearly $\mathcal{B}(r_{n},\frac{1}{m})\subset\mathcal{B}(x,\frac{2}{m})\subset G$
  which contradict our selections on $m_{n}$
 , thus $x\in\mathcal{B}(r_{n},\frac{1}{m_{n}})$
 . [(again,why?) Let $\alpha\in\mathcal{B}(r_{n},\frac{1}{m})$
 , then $d(\alpha,y)<1/m$
  it follows from the triangle inequality that $d(x,\alpha)\leqslant d(x,y)+d(y,\alpha)<\frac{2}{m}$
 ; hence $\alpha\in\mathcal{B}(x,\frac{2}{m})$
  and therefore $\mathcal{B}(r_{n},\frac{1}{m})\subset\mathcal{B}(x,\frac{2}{m})$
 ]. Now, since $x$
  was arbitrarly in $G$
 , it follows that for each $x\in G$
  there exists $n$
  such that $x\in\mathcal{B}(r_{n},\frac{1}{m_{n}})$
 ; hence $G\subset\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\mathcal{B}(r_{n},\frac{1}{m_{n}})$
 which shows that $G=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\mathcal{B}(r_{n},\frac{1}{m_{n}})$. $\square$

**Proposition to be proved:**

*Every open subset of $\mathbb{R}^{p}$ is the union of a countable collection of closed sets.*

*proof.* Let $G\ne\emptyset$
 , $G\subset\mathbb{R}^{p}$
  be open, let $\{r_{n}\::\: n\in\mathbb{N}\}$
  be an enumeration of all the rational points in $G$
 . Since, $G$
  is open for every $r_{n}$
  there exists an open ball $\mathcal{B}(r_{n},\varepsilon_{n})$
  contained in $G$ . Moreover, for each $r_{n}$
  there exists a closed ball $\overline{\mathcal{B}}(r_{n},\varepsilon_{n}-\frac{1}{m_{n}})\subset\mathcal{B}(r_{n},\varepsilon_{n})\subset\begin{subarray}{c}
G\end{subarray}$
 , where $m_{n}$
  is the smallest natural number such that $\varepsilon_{n}-\frac{1}{m_{n}}>0$
 . (i.e. $\frac{1}{m_{n}}<\varepsilon_{n}$
  ). Clearly,

$$\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\overline{\mathcal{B}}(r_{n},\varepsilon_{n}-\frac{1}{m_{n}})\subset G.$$

Now we pick an arbitrary $x\in G$
 , since $G$
  is open we can find a $\mathcal{B}(x,\varepsilon_{m})\subset G$; choose $m\in\mathbb{N}$
  so that $m$
  is the smallest number such that $\varepsilon_{m}-\frac{1}{m}>0$
  and $\overline{\mathcal{B}}(x,\varepsilon_{m}-\frac{1}{m})\begin{subarray}{c}
\subset\end{subarray}\mathcal{B}(x,\varepsilon_{m})$
 . Now, since $\varepsilon_{m}-\frac{1}{m}>0$
  it follows that there must exist a rational number $y\in\overline{\mathcal{B}}(x,\varepsilon_{m}-\frac{1}{m})$
 . [hence $y=r_{n}$
  for some $n$
  and $\mathcal{\overline{B}}(y,\varepsilon_{n}-\frac{1}{m_{n}})=\overline{\mathcal{B}}(r_{n},\varepsilon_{n}-\frac{1}{m_{n}})\subset\mathcal{B}(x,\varepsilon_{m})$
 ]. Suppose that $x\notin\overline{\mathcal{B}}(r_{n},\varepsilon_{n}-\frac{1}{m_{n}})$
 , then $d(x,y)>\varepsilon_{n}-\frac{1}{m_{n}}$
 , but we know $d(x,y)\leqslant\varepsilon_{m}-\frac{1}{m}$
  so it follows that $0<\varepsilon_{n}-\frac{1}{m_{n}}<\varepsilon_{m}-\frac{1}{m}$
 . Now, let $\alpha\in\overline{\mathcal{B}}(r_{n},\varepsilon_{n}-\frac{1}{m_{n}})$
  it follows that $d(\alpha,y)\leqslant\varepsilon_{n}-\frac{1}{m_{n}}$
  and that $d(x,\alpha)\leqslant d(\alpha,y)+d(y,x)\leqslant\left(\varepsilon_{n}-\frac{1}{m_{n}}\right)+\left(\varepsilon_{m}-\frac{1}{m}\right)$.

As you might see by now I am spinning my wheels and getting no where! If I could show that $x\in\overline{\mathcal{B}}(r_{n},\varepsilon_{n}-\frac{1}{m_{n}})$ then I would be done, or likewise if I could show $\overline{\mathcal{B}}(r_{n},\varepsilon_{n}-\frac{1}{m_{n}})\subset\overline{\mathcal{B}}(x,\varepsilon_{m}-\frac{1}{m})$ but I can't do either of these, because I don't have any way to relate $\varepsilon_{n}$ to $\varepsilon_{m}$. Perhaps my approach is entirely wrong. I would greatly appreciate some guidance, thanks!

Comment: You got it. Start it over on a fresh empty paper.

Comment: @Berci I don't see how I have it? I haven't used the fact that I chose $\frac{1}{m_n}$ to be the smallest natural number such that $\frac{1}{m_n}<\varepsilon_n$ yet, do I even need to assume this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are working entirely too hard. You already know that every open subset of $\Bbb R^n$ is the union of a countable collection of open balls, and I’m sure that you know that the union of a countable family of countable collections is still countable. Thus, all you have to do is show that every open ball in $\Bbb R^n$ is the union of a countable collection of closed sets. In fact you can show that every open ball in $\Bbb R^n$ is the union of a countable collection of closed **balls**, as the hint suggests. In all other respects, however, the hint is counterproductive, because there is no need to repeat the complexities of the argument for the earlier exercise.

Let $B(p,r)$ be the open ball in $\Bbb R^n$ of radius $r$ centred at $p$. Can you find a very simple countable family of closed balls whose union is $B(p,r)$? Think about it for a while; if you don’t see it, there’s a big hint in the spoiler-protected block below.

> You can even take the closed balls to be nested, with a common centre.

Comment: Funny how that question about transfinite arithmetic, shows its face in this question. Thanks! I can put it all together from here.

Comment: @Jimmy: Excellent. You’re welcome!

Comment: I understand that we can take the closed balls to be nested, with a common centre. Would you be however please be able to tell me how will the union of closed give an open ball?

Comment: @MathMan look at $\cup [1/n-1,1-1/n] = (-1,1)$

Comment: @AmerYR Yeah! Thanks!