# Rudin's RCA: proof of Theorem 1.40

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, proof-verification

This question is about the unanswered part of [Big Rudin 1.40: Open Set is a countable union of closed disks?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/426575/235690).  Specifically, in Rudin's Real and Complex Analysis, we have

[image]

---

My question:  It appears to me that the proof remains equally valid, if we let $\Delta$ be an **open** circular disk in $S^c$, doesn't it?  For we only need to make one other change to the proof above:

$$\mid A_E(f)-\alpha\mid = \frac{1}{\mu(E)}\left\vert\int_E (f-\alpha)d\mu\right\vert \le \frac{1}{\mu(E)}\int_E \left\vert(f-\alpha)\right\vert d\mu < r,$$

(which is also impossible, since $A_E(f)\in S.$)  Is this correct?  If I missed something, I'd appreciate it if someone can point it out.  Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the proof also works with open disks. One point that may have made Rudin prefer to use closed disks is that

$$g(x) \leqslant r \text{ for all } x \implies \int_E g\,d\mu \leqslant r\cdot \mu(E) \text{ for all measurable } E$$

is a wee bit easier to prove than

$$g(x) < r \text{ for all } x \implies \int_E g\,d\mu < r\cdot \mu(E) \text{ for all measurable $E$ with } 0 < \mu(E) < +\infty\,.$$

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer & esp. for the comments.  Indeed, on a 2nd thought, the strict inequality isn't as straightforward as I thought earlier.

Comment: Yes. It's not difficult to prove, all you need is an $\varepsilon > 0$ such that $\{ x : g(x) \leqslant r - \varepsilon\}$ has positive measure, but the nonstrict inequality is immediate.